# How to create an update function for multiple ImageViews?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an update function for multiple ImageView's but kept running into issues. I'm currently passing an individual ImageView to the `updateBlobPosition` function inside a timer, which works fine for one ImageView. But as soon I pass a second ImageView (blob2), now both ImageViews mimic each other as they have the same trajectory and velocity.

In addition, when one ImageView hits a wall and bounces back, the other one does the same. What I want is for each ImageView to be independent of each other. Any help would be appreciated.

```
...
blob1.setX(generateRandomNumber(0, 930));
blob1.setY(generateRandomNumber(0, 1750));
blob2.setX(generateRandomNumber(0, 930));
blob2.setY(generateRandomNumber(0, 1750));
...

//start the timer
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    playerMovement();
                    updateBlobPosition(blob1);
                    updateBlobPosition(blob2);
                    collision(blob1);
                    collision(blob2);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 20);

...
protected ImageView updateBlobPosition(ImageView blob) {

    blobX = blob.getX();
    blobY = blob.getY();

    blobX += blobVelocityX;
    blobY += blobVelocityY;

    //left
    if ((blob.getX() + blobVelocityX < 0)) {
        blobVelocityX = -blobVelocityX;
    }
    //right
    else if (blob.getX() - blobVelocityX > 930) {
        blobVelocityX = -Math.abs(blobVelocityX);
    }
    //top
    if ((blob.getY() + blobVelocityY < -20)) {
        blobVelocityY = -blobVelocityY;
    }
    //bottom
    else if (blob.getY() - blobVelocityY > 1750) {
        blobVelocityY = -Math.abs(blobVelocityY);
    }

    blob.setX(blobX);
    blob.setY(blobY);

    return blob;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same velocity variables for both.  So of course they be updated in the same way.  If you want them to move independently, give them independent speeds.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What would be an efficient way of assigning independent velocities? I'm currently assigning the velocity outside of the update function, should the update function just take in two more parameters for velocityX and velocityY?

Comment: You could subclass `ImageView` and add an associated velocity member variable.

Notice how you can call `blob.getX()` - if you sub-classed and added velocity as a member variable of the `ImageView` you could then call `blob.getVelocityX()`. This would ensure every time you created a blob it would have a velocity associated with it.